# Call function from DLL based on some dynamic determined ordinal?

Tags: labview

Can I call a function from LabVIEW that is at certain ordinal in some DLL, while the ordinal is determined at run-time?

I'm also interested if there is something similar to function pointers, like in 'C' language, which hold some dynamic function address?

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to call function by address, you will have to develop a wrapper in C by compiling a DLL from a code like that:

```
typedef int (*real_func_type)(int);

int wrapper(size_t address, int param1)
{
    return ((real_func_type)address)(param1);
}
```

where real function proto is

```
int real_func(int param);
```

Comment: Well - I switched from 'C' to this language with the hope that it can fully replace it. Isn't there any LabView way of achieving this?

Comment: not that I know of. But may be your problem is a part of a bigger problem? Tell us what exactly are you trying to solve? Maybe some new architectural design or something will work out.

Comment: If you want to 'fully replace' your C code with LabVIEW, does that include the code in the DLL?

Answer (score 0):

If your second question is whether LabVIEW has something similar to a function pointer, then the answer is that the closest thing is a VI reference. There are different types of VI references and different ways of creating and using them, so you would need to read up on that.

In any case, VI references are purely a LabVIEW construct. There's no mechanism for interacting with C function pointers directly and you can't create a function pointer to a VI and give that to the DLL function. For something like that you would also need some wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

In your block diagram, create a case structure that takes your ordinal value. In each frame of the case structure, invoke the appropriate function from the DLL.

Comment: This wouldn't work in my case as I would like the number of DLL ordinals to be determined at run-time.

Comment: Then you are completely out of luck. LabVIEW, by design, has no facility for doing that kind of pointer manipulation. The wrapper DLL solution above is your only option.